# culture invariant object ToString()

Tags: .net, formatting, culture, cultureinfo

How can I call `ToString()` on an object and make it use the invariant culture?
There are overloads for `ToString()` on objects that implement `IConvertible` (like bool, int, float..), but what if the object in question is not `IConvertible`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think `IFormattable` is the relevant interface. It has a `ToString` method that lets you specify the format provider, which can be a culture.

Comment: Since a culture is a format provider, you can use it with `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", value)`

Comment: Please use `string` instead of `String` as recommended.

Comment: @nitzel: C# isn't the only language in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 51):

The `System.Convert` class has a static `ToString` overload that takes an `object`.

```
Convert.ToString(obj, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Based on [my benchmarks](http://share.linqpad.net/xvjr8e.linq), this is roughly twice as fast as `string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", value)` and, more importantly, it looks cleaner. However, if you are building a string already, I'd recommend FormattableString.Invariant.

```
FormattableString.Invariant($"Object value: {obj}")
```

Comment: "and looks cleaner" not if you began with a string interpolation with multiple items to be escaped. With `string.Format`, it does them all at once.

Comment: @jeromej: That's a good point, although if you're using string interpolation I'd recommend `FormattableString.Invariant` for improved readability. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Convert.ToString(Object, IFormatProvider) overload internally makes use of casts to IConvertible and IFormattable and uses instance method Object.Tostring() as a fallback. The implementation if identical in .NET Framework 4.8 and current .NET.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,6a1a2c3ac58e60dd
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/28f6daaaf825f167aa1808291cf56bf16234e48a/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Convert.cs#L1924